# issubclass(type,type) = True why?

Tags: python, object, types

python2.7

```
>>> issubclass(type,type)
True
>>> issubclass(object,object)
True
>>> issubclass(object,type)
False
```

I know that `object` is on the top of new-style class, so `type` is inherit from `object` . Since `object` is subclass of itself. Now I can get a chain like this:
`type` --> `object` --> `object` -X-> `type` .
How could `issubclass(type,type)` be `True`?

Comment: I would recommend an excellent article on this topic: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html#bring-in-the-objects

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#issubclass)

> A class is considered a subclass of itself